# What is the equivalent of scala companion objects in Java Akka?

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am trying to use Akka with Java, coming from a scala background. In scala, you define the case classes of an Actor in the actors companion object. What is the equivalent in Java?

Comment: Default  methods in interfaces with java 8?

Comment: Take a look at `Notes for Java programmers` at http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html. In short, I believe that you'll put any `companion` appropriate fields into a `static` field of the Java class.

Comment: Inner classes to the Actor class are also an option, with the downside of more syntax (new ActorClass.MessageClass() .... )

Answer (score 1):

From what i know, there, unfortunately, is no such thing. You need do define the POJO classes by yourself. Still there are some libraries the can help with code enhancements.

Some good article about missings in java vs scala: https://jaxenter.com/the-10-most-annoying-things-about-java-after-using-scala-108012.html